# Android floating buttons over a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I was trying to have a floating button on my view, I googled and found this link which pretty well sums it up.

[http://www.jondev.net/articles/Floating_Views_in_Android_(Buttons)](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Floating_Views_in_Android_%28Buttons%29)

While this is true for one button, but what if i want to have two floating buttons one at "top left" and another at "bottom right".

I thought of having a relative layout which has two buttons with lay out gravities different. Will this work. I tried it and miserably failed. Has any one else tried to do this? Is there any way of doing this, if so please let me know.

Comment: The link says "Page doesn't exist".

Comment: nothing displayed in that link

Comment: @superM you need to add the closing ) to the link

Comment: @Thebestshoot, please edit your question and place that bracket properly

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achive that with a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that the last added Widget is on top.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `RelativeLayout` although you can also achieve that using `FrameLayout` (like in the example in your the link).
In `FrameLayout`Set a proper gravity to the the buttons (`Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT`, or via XML...), and in `RelativeLayout` set the reuiqred rules to the Buttons:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

etc.

Comment: I tried with the framelayout and i failed to make it work may be i am wrong in doing what i did , is it possible to elaborate please.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```